# Getting "NoSuchFlowExecutionException" exception while implementing CAS with SSL

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, cas

I am implementing CAS for Single Sign on Authentication, I have used SSL for the same.

I am getting following error,

```
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.NoSuchFlowExecutionException: No flow execution could be found with key '_c642A7AC9-3721-0813-DF9B-9B90458DB0C9_kD14EEF54-E743-8317-8735-825AB028366B' -- perhaps this executing flow has ended or expired? This could happen if your users are relying on browser history (typically via the back button) that references ended flows.; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.conversation.NoSuchConversationException: No conversation could be found with id '642A7AC9-3721-0813-DF9B-9B90458DB0C9' -- perhaps this conversation has ended? 
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.support.AbstractConversationFlowExecutionRepository.getConversation(AbstractConversationFlowExecutionRepository.java:229)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.support.AbstractConversationFlowExecutionRepository.getLock(AbstractConversationFlowExecutionRepository.java:119)
org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resume(FlowExecutorImpl.java:217)
org.springframework.webflow.executor.support.FlowRequestHandler.handleFlowRequest(FlowRequestHandler.java:111)
org.springframework.webflow.executor.mvc.FlowController.handleRequestInternal(FlowController.java:165)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:115)
org.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilterInternal(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:48)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)


root cause 

org.springframework.webflow.conversation.NoSuchConversationException: No conversation could be found with id '642A7AC9-3721-0813-DF9B-9B90458DB0C9' -- perhaps this conversation has ended? 
org.springframework.webflow.conversation.impl.ConversationContainer.getConversation(ConversationContainer.java:107)
org.springframework.webflow.conversation.impl.SessionBindingConversationManager.getConversation(SessionBindingConversationManager.java:125)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.support.AbstractConversationFlowExecutionRepository.getConversation(AbstractConversationFlowExecutionRepository.java:227)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.support.AbstractConversationFlowExecutionRepository.getLock(AbstractConversationFlowExecutionRepository.java:119)
org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resume(FlowExecutorImpl.java:217)
org.springframework.webflow.executor.support.FlowRequestHandler.handleFlowRequest(FlowRequestHandler.java:111)
org.springframework.webflow.executor.mvc.FlowController.handleRequestInternal(FlowController.java:165)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:115)
org.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilterInternal(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:48)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

If anyone has idea about this one, please guide.

Thanks.

Got some clue, something related to "login-webflow.xml", finding...if anyone get..plz revert back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done, It was the issue with the certificate name, gave the certificate name as the machine number and it worked.